# Mysql: Select rows from 2 tables that are not in a third table

Tags: mysql

i have three tables employees, customers and account. i want to select all the rows that are found in employees and customers but not in account. i tried SELECT *FROM employees, customers where id not in (select id from account) and it did not work, but if i remove either employees or customers it works

Answer (score 1):

If neither employee or customer has an account you could union the 2 tables then test

```
with cte as
(
Select 'e' src,id, name from employees
union all
Select 'c' src,id, name from customers
)
select * 
from cte 
where not exists (select 1 from accounts where accounts_id = cte.id);
```

Or you could use a cross join (or a comma join without a where clause)

```
SELECT  
FROM employees e, customers c 
where not exists (select 1 from accounts where accounts_id = e.id) and
      not exists (select 1 from accounts where accounts_id = c.id);
```

The point being that you have to test the id from both tables. With a union there is one id to test with a cross join there are two. Using a not exists means the query is more efficient than an in(s).